# in flutter dart must i add the same name for pakage and application id

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

in flutter dart now I want to run an app but it gives me some error
I think maybe it's because of their name pleasewhat can I do

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
D:\medicaldnghfhx\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-25 value=(ak.kurdaid)
    has a different value=(ak.kurdaid) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-29
    Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
        flavorName {
            applicationId = "ak.kurdaid"
        }

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
```

Comment: Please check your application id is same in your main androidManifest file also check in debug and profile manifest file

Comment: i updated the question yes its the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check these files and see if you have the correct `applicationId`:

```
src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml
src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
src/main/AdroidManifest.xml
```